# Python ctypes stack corruption

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm having weird issues with ctypes where by it appears to be corrupting the stack by dereferencing a pointer when it shouldn't be. The setup is fairly complicated by stay with me for a second.

I have a C function `qfsm_search` with wrapped signature like this:

```
qmotion.qfsm_search.argtypes = [
    qfsm_ptr,
    qfsm_node_t,
    qskel_ptr,
    vec3, c_int,
    qfsm_node_ptr,
    POINTER(c_int)]
qmotion.qfsm_search.restype = None
```

I then output all of the details of the parameters and call it in python like this:

```
print("Fsm: %d | %X" % (sizeof(fsm), addressof(fsm.contents)))
print("Curr: %d | %d %d %d" % (sizeof(curr), curr.state, curr.anim, curr.frame))
print("Skel: %d | %X" % (sizeof(skel), addressof(skel.contents)))
print("Tar: %f %f %f" % (tar.x, tar.y, tar.z))
print("Limit: %i" % limit)
print("Out: %X" % addressof(out_nodes_p.contents))
print("Out Num: %X" % addressof(out_num_p.contents))

qmotion.qfsm_search(fsm, curr, skel, tar, limit, out_nodes_p, out_num_p)
```

This outputs the following on the python side. All appears to be fine so far.

```
Fsm: 8 | 13CF0960
Curr: 12 | 0 0 89
Skel: 8 | 49193E60
Tar: 100.000000 100.000000 100.000000
Limit: 5
Out: 39A4FD10
Out Num: 2D623510
```

Then in C I have the function like this:

```
void qfsm_search(qfsm_t* fsm, qfsm_node_t curr, qskel_t* skel, vec3 tar, int max_out, qfsm_node_t* out, int* out_num) {

  qdebug("Fsm: %d | %p", (int)sizeof(fsm), fsm);
  qdebug("Node: %d | %d %d %d", (int)sizeof(curr), curr.state, curr.anim, curr.frame);
  qdebug("Skel: %d | %p", (int)sizeof(skel), skel);
  qdebug("Tar: %f %f %f", tar.x, tar.y, tar.z);
  qdebug("Max: %d", max_out);
  qdebug("Out: %p", out);
  qdebug("Out Num: %p", out_num);

  ....
```

But this function outputs:

```
Fsm: 8 | 0000000013CF0960
Node: 12 | 0 0 89
Skel: 8 | 000000000D6281A8
Tar: 0.000000 0.000000 14144512.000000
Max: 967112848
Out: 000000000D628468
Out Num: 0000000000000005
```

Notice how the value of the `skel` parameter has changed and the stack following after it is corrupt. The reason I believe that ctypes is dereferencing the `skel` parameter is that if I set `skel` to be a NULL pointer then I get a NULL pointer segfault before the C function is entered and any debugging information is printed.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be going on? I suspected it may have been some weird issue with the type `qskel_ptr`, but this seems unlikely because of the behavior I explained when passing in NULL pointer.

It is probably worth mentioning that I am running Windows 7 64-bit and Python 2.6.4. I have also managed to reproduce the behavior on Python 2.7.3

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not being able to help more - but a good hint there is the "0000005" received as "Out Num" on the C side -- I'd think it might be the same "5" that should be in teh max/limit parameter - (the odds of a "5" appearing as a 64 bit integer in corrupt memory are quite small).  If that is the case, ctypes is putting 12 - 16 extra bytes beyond the 8 expected for the pointer size.

You probably already have, but double check the definition of your "skel" object on the Python side  - specially, compare it with the working "fsm" object which is working properly - and if that don't give you a hint, please paste any differences you find in both declarations on an update to your question.

Comment: Thanks jsbueno, yes you are right about the "5", I checked it by changing the value. Will look a bit deeper if I can into the skel object to see if I can find any clues. I don't want to out rule that it is a bug in ctypes or python and may try to update the python install if it doesn't prove too difficult (it is included in a maya install).